# Is there a query tool for Cassandra (or other noSQL DBs) similar to QTADO or navicat?

Tags: cassandra

There are many query tools for SQL databases, e.g. QTADO, navicat, etc. Are there similar tools for Cassandra and other noSQL databases? I need it mostly for testing during development of Cassandra apps.

Answer (score 1):

Playorm supports S-SQL for Cassandra and you can use it's command line tool to execute SQL statements. For more details visit http://buffalosw.com/wiki/Command-Line-Tool/

Answer (score 1):

Aqua Data Studio has a native interface to it, not sure how much functionality it supports, link is below. I have no stake or interest in ADS, just looking for some tools as well.

http://www.aquafold.com/dbspecific/apache_cassandra_client.html

Answer (score 1):

Aqua Data Studio is great for Cassandra, MongoDb and many other NoSQL and SQL DBs. Unfortunately its  pricey (499) for an average Joe and they don't have a community license.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, i don't think there is any such  tool for cassandra. Though  viewer tool are available, say Datastax Opscenter, tool developed by the company behind cassandra. Also TOAD for NOSQL is also available.

Answer (score 0):

Datastax OpsCenter is probably the closest thing to those tools, but if you just want something for testing during development, you may find cqlsh meets your needs well. It's bundled with Cassandra.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the OLEDB provider for Cassandra, and QTADO tool (with CQL3 commands).

Answer (score 0):

RazorSQL has support for Cassandra.

http://www.razorsql.com/articles/razorsql_apache_cassandra.html

It's commercial but has a 30 day trial.

Answer (score 0):

I use Visual Studio Code and https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools extension. It supports various db-s, including cassandra.